# Raspberry Pi が USB からの起動に失敗する

Tags: raspberry-pi

つい最近、初めてRaspberry Pi (4, Model B)に触れて、教本を基に基礎を学習中の者です。

さてタイトルにもある通り、起動不良に悩まされています。具体的には、以下の通りです。(なお、OSはMicro SDではなく、スティック型のUSBでブートしています。)

①USBを挿した状態で電源を入れると、緑のLEDが３回連続の点滅を繰り返す
②USBを抜いた状態で起動すると、緑のLEDは点灯。ブートローダーは表示されず。
③②の状態からUSBを挿すと点滅に切り替わるものの画面は変わらず。
④ディスプレイにはHDMIで接続、買ったばかりのケーブルだが、このケーブルが原因であるかは現時点で確認取れず。
⑤OSの入ったUSBはRaspberry Pi OSでOSのフォーマットと再インストールを行ったが解決には至らず。
⑥電源不足かと思いUSB Cケーブルを5V3A出力の、ZenFone10 付属のもので試したが、これも解決に至らず。

以上です。よろしくおねがいいたします。

Comment: USBメモリのメーカー/モデルを変えるとか、普通にMicroSDでやってみるとか試してみては？ [Raspberry Pi 4でUSBブートがうまくいかなかった原因](https://ytooyama.hatenadiary.jp/entry/2022/08/04/094928), [Raspberry pi インジケーターランプ(ACTライト)の意味](https://qiita.com/napspans/items/cb2737eadae48118f8c5), [Raspberry Pi 4をUSBブートさせる](https://note.com/fumix/n/n0af975e5b339), [ラズパイ4をUSB接続のSSDから起動する方法(USBブート)](https://raspida.com/rpi4-ssd-usb-boot)

Comment: 購入後、ブートローダーのバージョンを確認するために、周辺機器やUSBなしで起動させました。そのときは正常に動作したのですが、今はディスプレイに表示されませんでした。おそらく違うUSBにしても解決しないのかなと思います。config.txt覗くとHDMIについて一切の記載がなく、この辺が怪しい気がします。

Comment: こんな記事を見つけました。[USBメモリブートしたRaspiは USBエラーで巻き込み死亡する](https://takuya-1st.hatenablog.jp/entry/2024/01/13/083000) ここの作者に「Raspberry自体がまともに動かなくなった。」というのがどういう症状なのか聞いてみてはどうでしょう？ 同じサイトにはこんな記事もあるので何かリカバリの参考になるかも。[raspi4 が起動しなくなった（EEPROMエラー）のでなおした。](https://takuya-1st.hatenablog.jp/entry/2023/06/08/184425)

Comment: 参考になりそうな記事、ありがとうございます。そちらのブログも一読して、解決方法を探っていこうと思います。今回の反省点としては恐らく、電源オフ時でも無闇矢鱈にOSの入ったUSBを抜き差ししないこと 、シャットダウンは必ずデスクトップ側から行うことの徹底(スイッチ付きの通電ケーブルである必要はない)、といったところだと自負しています。進展あり次第、こちらでも報告させていただきます

Answer (score -1):

たんにそのUSBメモリがブートできる状態のものではない、ってことですね。
まずは、MicroSDで起動できることを確認したあとで、USBメモリのブートイメージを作っていくなどしてみては。

たんにブートイメージをコピーするだけではできませんよ

Comment: 情報元を示したほうがよいと思うので, URL貼っておきます。[LED警告点滅コード (LED warning flash codes)](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/configuration.html#led-warning-flash-codes) 3回は => 一般的な起動失敗

Comment: ラズパイ OS ImagerからUSBにインストールしたのですが、最初の頃は問題なく起動できていました。USBのフォーマット、OS再インストールもしたのですが原因はここではないようです。